Can 'as much as' be replaced by 'as well as' in 'Sam retorted that it was my fault as much as his.'?

Sam retorted that it was my fault as much as his.

Is there any differences between '...it was my fault as much as his.' and '...it was my fault as well as his.'?

The difference is my fault as much as his means we were both equally to blame, whereas with my fault as well as his one of us may be more at fault than the other.

The title and the post body ask different questions. The title asks if one phrase can be replaced by another (Yes: both expressions are equally grammatical, but that subtly changes the meaning of the clause). The body asks if the phrases mean the same thing (No: As the Answers have already explained).

@Syntax Junkie Thanks for your pointing out. With the title, one might just give a yes or no without further explanation.

No.
If it is your fault as well as his, it means that you are both at fault, but it does not mean that you are equally at fault.  If it is your fault as much as his, it means you are equally at fault.
If your picnic was rained out because neither of you checked the weather report, you are as much at fault as he is.  If he falsely assured you that he had checked, and you knew he wasn't that reliable, you are at fault as well as he is, but still he is the main one at fault.

I interpreted it slightly diffierently: as well as means that you admit you were at fault, but as much as seems to suggest that if you were at fault, then I was too (but you may not think you did anything wrong).

I think there's also a subtly implied "at least"—if it's your fault as much as mine, I'm not saying I blame you more, but I'm not not saying that…

No, they are not interchangeable as @Mary already gave an example for.
However, that example overlooks the use of the word retorted from the Cambridge dictionary definition:

to answer someone quickly in an angry or funny way

This word is crucial to the meaning (without any other context provided).
A retort here would generally mean that someone (Person A) is accusing Person B of being responsible for something, and that Person A believes they have done nothing wrong so they can point the finger at Person B.
Person B, being accused, then throws it back at Person A saying "it was my fault as much as yours". The implication here from Person B is "You think it wasn't your fault. Well, it's exactly the same for me".
As a side note, another construction of this argument would be "you're as much to blame as me" when Person B is accepting fault but wants to get Person A to accept the same level of culpability.
